# memory issue nsobject and nsmutablearray UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I added a simple collection view and i add items fetched from my backend , when I add all the objects to a nsmutablearray it takes less memory but when I add the fetched objects to a NSObject while scrolling the collection view it takes more memory .

here is a sample code

**myObjectModel.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface myObjectModel: NSObject


@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *objectTitle;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *objectDesc;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *objectImgURL;

- (id)initWithObjectTitle:(NSString *)dTitle
             objectImgURL:(NSString *)dObjectImgURL
               objectDesc:(NSString *)dObjectDesc;
@end
```

**myObjectModel.m**

```
#import "myObjectModel.h"

@implementation myObjectModel

- (id)initWithObjectTitle:(NSString *)dTitle
             objectImgURL:(NSString *)dObjectImgURL
               objectDesc:(NSString *)dObjectDesc {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
       self.objectTitle = dTitle;
       self.objectImgURL = dObjectImgURL;
       self.objectDesc = dObjectDesc;
    }
    return self;
}

@end;
```

then I imported this header to my UIViewController which has a collectionview while fetching all the objects i add this method to add those objects and then save them into a nsmutablearray

```
     BackendlessDataQuery *query = [BackendlessDataQuery query];
          query.queryOptions.pageSize = @(100); //set page size
        [[backendless.persistenceService of:[Channels class]] find:query response:^(BackendlessCollection *backendlessObjects) {

            NSArray *currentPage = [backendlessObjects getCurrentPage];
    NSMutableArray *arrData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            for (Objects *objects in currentPage) {

                @autoreleasepool {

   myObjectModel *dataItem = [[myObjectModel alloc]initWithObjectTitle:backendlessObjects.title
             objectImgURL:backendlessObjects.image
               objectDesc:backendlessObjects.Desc;



        [arrData addObject:dataItem];
    }
//Test is a nsarray added in the header file
self.test = arrData;
[self.collectionView reloadData];
} error:^(Fault *fault) {



    }];
```

here is what I add to my collection data source

```
#pragma mark - UICollectionViewDatasource

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView; {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return [test count];
}

    - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        myCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"data" forIndexPath:indexPath];

       myObjectModel *dataItem = (myObjectModel*)[test objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       // cell.objectTitle.text = dataItem.objectTitle;



        [cell.channelImg sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:dataItem.objectImgURL] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NoImage.png"]];

        return cell;
    }
```

when I run this code all my objects will appear in the collectionview but while scrolling the memory keeps increasing.

Comment: i didnt get your question.

Comment: Are you reusing the `collectionViewCells`? Please share the `dataSource` of your `collectionView`.

Comment: Are you trying to put the fetched array into Core Data? Is that why the NSObject? Be more clear to get help.

Comment: Let A = memory size of array, and B = memory size of collection view and cells.  It seems right to expect that A+B > A.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to increase memory by using test Array the reason is by using this

```
[cell.channelImg sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:dataItem.objectImgURL] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NoImage.png"]];
```

this will Asynchronously download image from URL.if you comment above line then it may not increase memory.